# Can key presses be throttled on Linux?

Tags: keyboard, xbindkeys

I've got a keyboard (razor black widow stealth) that is malfunctioning in such a way that it periodically sends duplicate key presses for various keys (`h` and `n`) so far. I'm looking for ways to delay the purchase of a new one in software.

I'm currently on Kubuntu 18.04. Is there any way to throttle key presses so that 2 key presses of the same key within 500ms (for example) would only register as a single key press? I tried extending the duration of repeat delay to see if it was just being pressed too long but it does look like the keyboard is sending duplicate presses.

Comment: Could it be a defective keyboard?

Comment: It definitely is a defective keyboard. I'm trying to compensate for it.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is consistent, you could rig xdotool (install with `sudo apt-get install xdotool -y` to press backspace immediately after each of these keypresses to delete one of the two keystrokes, then set up a keyboard shortcut to each of the trouble keys to run `xdotool key Delete sleep 1`. What this does is has xdotool send the delete command immediately after the first keypress, but then provides a 1 second delay for the second keystroke to be sent through. Tested it on my own machine and it made it so that a single keypress wouldn't get sent through, but a quick double-press would.

If you need an inexpensive keyboard to get you through until you can get a new good quality one, thrift stores usually have large stocks of old (but clean)  USB office keyboards that can tie you over for $3-5, and you would have it immediately. Nothing flashy, but comfortable enough for typing and gaming so long as you aren't pressing more than 5 keys at once.

Comment: Unfortunately it's totally random. Sometimes it's fine and sometimes I get two `h`. Thanks for mentioning xdotool though, I didn't know about that tool. The real issue is that I actually like this keyboard but it just breaks down every two years. Trying to justify keeping it.