# Kubuntu disable "alt" to menu shortcut

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the "Alt" key for many keyboard shortcuts within visual studio code. But the moment I press "Alt" the cursor moves away from the text editor and up to the menu bar, opening a menu there.

How can I disable or change this default functionality of the "Alt" key?

I do not want a solution that requires me to hide the menu bar, as I use that.

Comment: Same question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187994/stop-alt-from-opening-searching-menus-on-kubuntu